# Changing cell values in a row conditioned on values of another row

Tags: r, data.table, strsplit

I'm trying to change a data frame with several thousands of rows that each look like one of the following variations:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> a </th>
    <th> b </th>
    <th> c </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> $10 x and $7 y </td>
    <td> NA </td>
    <td> NA </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> $70 a; $95 b </td>
    <td> NA </td>
    <td> NA </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> $6 j </td>
    <td> NA </td>
    <td> NA </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and change it into this:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th> a </th>
        <th> b </th>
        <th> c </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> $10 x and $7 y </td>
        <td> $10 x </td>
        <td> $7 y </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> $70 a; $95 b </td>
        <td> $70 a </td>
        <td> $95 b </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> $6 j </td>
        <td> $6 j </td>
        <td> NA </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

This is my current code to accomplish this (I use the number of dollar signs because that is the only consistent value to determine number of transactions):

(This is formatted as a data.table, just in case that makes a difference)

```
  df$b[(str_count(df$a, pattern = "\\$") == 2)] = unlist(strsplit(df$a, " and "))[1]
  df$c[(str_count(df$a, pattern = "\\$") == 2)] = unlist(strsplit(df$a, " and "))[2]
  df$b[str_count(df$a, pattern = "\\$") < 2] = df$a
```

Now, instead of the desired result, I get the following:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> a </th>
    <th> b </th>
    <th> c </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> $10 x and $7 y </td>
    <td> $10 x </td>
    <td> $7 y </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> $70 a; $95 b </td>
    <td> $10 x</td>
    <td> $7 y</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> $6 j </td>
    <td> $6 j </td>
    <td> NA </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I think it has to do with the fact that the `strsplit()` is taking the first subsetted row and applying it to every row in the subset, but I don't know how to change it to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try and write code to parse HTML, just call an HTML parser:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

stage1 <- 
  "<table>
  <tr>
    <th> a </th>
    <th> b </th>
    <th> c </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> $10 x and $7 y </td>
    <td> NA </td>
    <td> NA </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> $70 a; $95 b </td>
    <td> NA </td>
    <td> NA </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> $6 j </td>
    <td> NA </td>
    <td> NA </td>
  </tr>
</table>" %>% 
  rvest::minimal_html() %>% 
  rvest::html_node("table") %>% 
  rvest::html_table() %>% 
  as_tibble()

stage1

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  a              b     c    
  <chr>          <lgl> <lgl>
1 $10 x and $7 y NA    NA   
2 $70 a; $95 b   NA    NA   
3 $6 j           NA    NA
```

Now clean up `stage1` using `separate` and a regex

```
stage1 %>% 
  select(a) %>% 
  separate(col = "a", into = c("b", "c"), 
           sep = "(?ix) \\s* (and|;) \\s*",   # Perl stye regex, cases insensitive.
           remove = FALSE, 
           fill= "right")


  a              b     c    
  <chr>          <chr> <chr>
1 $10 x and $7 y $10 x $7 y 
2 $70 a; $95 b   $70 a $95 b
3 $6 j           $6 j  NA
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - thanks for your excellent solution! I've got to get better with regex, I think!

Comment: Lots of good material on regex out there.  In the present context, look at
https://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html#matching-patterns-with-regular-expressions
Although he doesn't cover Perl-style, or look-ahead/behind .  But it's pretty readable, and the exercises are worth practicing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_split_fixed` from `stringr`

```
stringr::str_split_fixed(df$a, '\\s*(;|and)\\s*', 2)

#       [,1]    [,2]   
#[1,] "$10 x" "$7 y" 
#[2,] "$70 a" "$95 b"
#[3,] "$6 j"  ""
```